# when I build and analyze, I got potential leak on at this point

Tags: iphone

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


    [self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];



    [[controlfile alloc]scedule1];   
    return YES;
}
```

i got potential leak of an object allocated on [[controlfile alloc]scedule1] when i build & analyze

Comment: Can you please be more specific so people don't have to guess what you're asking?

Comment: I would say you are leaking at: `[[controlfile alloc]scedule1];` you have alloced `controlfile` where is the release of the allocated memory? Provide more code and be more specific on your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[[controlfile alloc]scedule1];
```

This is allocating an instance of class `controlfile` and then calling `scedule1` on the allocated object. (Note that it's not yet initialized; you should have initialized it first by calling `init`). Then the object (which you allocated) is never referenced again. Thus, you have leaked it.

You really need to do something like this:

```
id controlfile = [[ControlFile alloc] init];
[controlfile scedule1];
[controlfile release];
```

This assumes that `ControlFile` is a class. If it's an instance variable (as indicated by the all lowercase text and lack of declaration in your code), then you want this:

```
controlfile = [[WhateverTheDeclaredClassOfControlFileIs alloc] init];
[controlfile scedule1];

// In the -dealloc method, call this:
[controlfile release];
```

For every call to `alloc`, you must call either `release` or `autorelease` when you are done with the object. You are not doing that here, and thus you have leaked the object.

Comment: Stole the words right out of my mouth. Yea that's right, all of them. I would have said it exactly that same way. Uncanny, aint it? heh. +1